# Is the density function of $|X|$ given by $f_{|X|}(x) = 2f_X(x)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with density $f_X$ such that $X$ has the same distribution as $-X$. Evaluate if the following statement is true or false and bubble in your solution:

**Statement:** The density of the random variable $|X|$ is given by $f_{|X|}(x) = 2f_X(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

---

I just wanted to ensure that my reasoning was sound on this question. For the density of $X$ to have the same distribution as $-X$ we must have something symmetric. Ie. we can essentially "fold" the part of the distribution left of the $y$-axis over the positive $x$ values which is why I think this would be correct. I just wanted to make sure that I did not miss any hidden caveat of the question.

Comment: Please do not post unsearchable pictures.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is right.

To formalize just notice that if $x > 0$:
$$ P(|X| \leq x) = 1 - P(|X| > x) = 1 - (P(X > x)+P(X<-x)) = 1 - (P(X > x)+P(-X > x))  $$

So,
$$ P(|X| \leq x) = 1 - 2P(X > x) = 1 - 2(1- P(X \leq x))  $$

In terms of the cdfs:
$$ F_{|X|} (x) = 2F_X(x) - 1\text{ when } x> 0 $$

Clearly, $F_{|X|} (x) = 0$ when $x\leq 0$.

We can take the derivative when $x>0$ and so:
$$ f_{|X|}(x) = \begin{cases} 2f_X(x)\text{, if }x > 0\\ 0\text{, if }x\leq 0 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

> > The density function of $\lvert X\rvert$ is given by $f_{\small \lvert X\rvert}(x)=2f_{\small X}(x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

> I just wanted to ensure that my reasoning was sound on this question. For the density of X to have the same distribution as -X we must have something symmetric. Ie. we can essentially "fold" the part of the distribution left of the y-axis over the positive x values which is why I think this would be correct.

What about the *negative* values for $x$?

Consider that if the statement was correct, then $f_{\small\lvert X\rvert}$ would not be a valid density function, because taking the integral *for all* values in $\Bbb R$ would give:

$$\int_\Bbb R f_{\small\lvert X\rvert}(x)\mathrm d x=2\int_\Bbb R f_{\small X}(x)\mathrm d x\\=2$$

---

You have the correct approach, but note that the folding maps a positive value and a negative value for $X$ onto a single *positive* value for $\lvert X\rvert$, and **no** values for $X$ will map to a *negative* for $\lvert X\rvert$ (which, of course, cannot be negative).

Perhaps the use of the token $x$ as the value for $\lvert X\rvert$ is confusing.

Let $Y=\lvert X\rvert$.  Then when $Y=y$, for any $y\in[0..\infty)$, there are two values for $X$, which are $\{y,-y\}$.

$$f_{\small Y}(y)~{= ( f_{\small X}(-y)+f_{\small X}(y) )\,\mathbf 1_{y\geqslant 0}\\=2 f_{\small X}(y)\,\mathbf 1_{y\geqslant 0} }$$

---

Thus we have a valid probability density function when we include the support.
$$\begin{align}f_{\small \lvert X\rvert}(x) &= 2 f_{\small X}(x)\,\mathbf 1_{x\geqslant 0} \\[2ex]\int_\Bbb R f_{\small\lvert X\rvert}(x)\,\mathrm d x&=\int_0^\infty 2 f_{\small X}(x)\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&= 1\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh! So by folding it over are you essentially saying I am creating a half-normal distribution both to the right and left of the y axis, hence you get 2 when you integrate over R?

Comment: No.  By folding you are placing all of the distribution to the right of the axis. It will therefore only be twice as dense over the positive values, and have zero density over the negatives. @user690808 .

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a tad bit lost so we essentially have a half-normal distribution where all negative numbers map to its absolute value so when you look at f(|-3|) we use f(3) to calculate its probability. So seemingly the idea of just multiplying the marginal density by 2 works. But how come it breaks down when integrating?

Comment: The absolute value random variable cannot be negative. Its density function is not supported there.$$f_{\small\lvert X\rvert}(x)=\begin{cases} 2\,f_{\small X}(x)&:&x\geqslant 0\\ 0&:&x<0\end{cases}$$